# How to fix ConcurrentModificationExceptions in game using multithreading for movement and sprite creation?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm attempting to create a game using threads for sprite creation and movement -- however, sometimes I can barely run it because I keep getting ConcurrentModificationExceptions. I was wondering if anybody could help me figure out how to make these errors stop happening so often.

I've tried adding "synchronized" to methods that are updating objects that run along the thread and using iterators, to no avail. Here are all the functions I have that use the thread:

Most of my errors occur from the last "update" method, or the "updateScene" method.

```
    public class ProjectileLauncher implements Runnable {
    private Model model;
    private View view;

    public ProjectileLauncher(Model model, View view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        if (!(model.getHero().isNotDead())) {
            System.out.println("You lose!");
        }
        while (model.getGameNotPaused()) {
            model.updateScene(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
            view.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press R to resume game.");
            }
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void updateScene(int width, int height) {
    Iterator<Sprite> iterator = sprites.iterator();
        if (hero.isNotDead()) {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Sprite spriteObject = iterator.next();
                if (spriteObject instanceof Fireball) {
                    ((Fireball) spriteObject).updateState();
                    /*
                    if (spriteObject.overlaps(hero, 100, 135)) {
                        hero.fireballHit();
                        iterator.remove();
                    }
                    */
                } if (spriteObject instanceof Arrow) {
                    ((Arrow) spriteObject).updateState();
                    if (spriteObject.overlaps(dragon, 350, 350)) {
                        dragon.arrowHit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

public synchronized void update(Graphics g) {
    Iterator<Sprite> iterator = sprites.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next().updateImage(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line does the exception occur?

Comment: They're usually occurring on the line "iterator.next().updateImage(g)" in the update method or "Sprite spriteObject = iterator.next();" of the updateScene method